# how to get CallBack From DialogFragment into activity

Tags: android

I have a dialogFragment extending BottomSheetDialogFragment. how i can call a method of activity, when this dialogfragment got dismiss.

please help me.. thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First set the listener for Dialog. Check this [Note: DialogFragment own the Dialog.setOnCancelListener and Dialog.setOnDismissListener callbacks. You must not set them yourself. To find out about these events, override onCancel(DialogInterface) and onDismiss(DialogInterface).](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html#setOnDismissListener(android.content.DialogInterface.OnDismissListener))

Comment: I got another solution. This was not working properly.